# BOT framework sample 12 implementation on ServiceNow

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using [sample12](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat) to create a minimizable webchat on the ServiceNow page. Using sample 12 and building the same, I was able to import it to ServiceNow and get to the point where it appears on a new UI page. But there are two issues 1) CORS 2)Authentication to the BOT isnt happening.[image]

Also, how do I take care of authentication?

I used the following [process](https://medium.com/@pishchulin/react-application-in-servicenow-8bdbb1e69c0c) to host the page

Any ideas ?
This sort of embed (as shown below) is working for us. But we need a minimizable webchat on servicenow

[image: ready]

Comment: How are you looking to use bot authentication with respect to the rest of the page? Is it to authenticate users to access page functionality, authenticate the bot to the page so it works, or something else?

Comment: So a user logs in to service now. I can get those details from these fields userID: c.data.botUserEmail,
username: c.data.botUserEmail and then can pass on to the chatbot. We have a sort of embed webchat ready but we need more like the minimizable chat. I shall update the things I have tried on the main question now.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Could you suggest please on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now got this working by hosting a app service returning the token. The app is now able to access the BOT.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using WebApplication1.Controllers;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DirectLineController : Controller
    {
        //[HttpPost]
        //public async Task<string> PartialToken()
        //{
        //    string data = await GetToken(false);
        //    return data;
        //}


        //[HttpGet]
        //public async Task<string> Token()
        //{
        //    string data = await GetToken(true);
        //    return data;
        //}
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            string data = String.Empty;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",
                    "Hir-4RmrbUY.cwA.aqo.ojSLtakhThiswontworkdonteventrym64oi_2LE_sB4C5BizQwaCg__q1M");
                var response = await client.PostAsync("https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate", null);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var raw = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    if (true)
                    {
                        data = raw;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data = JObject.Parse(raw)["token"].Value<string>();
                    }
                }
            }

            return data;
        }

        //protected override void ExecuteCore()
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}
    }
}
```