# How do I pass browser properties to react app talking to MSBOT?

Tags: reactjs, botframework

We have hosted a bot on ServiceNow and would now like to pass attributes from the browser to the BOT. How can I make this happen?

This question is actually part 2 of a question [I had posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834760/bot-framework-sample-12-implementation-on-servicenow) & which I have already found a solution for.
Since the BOT is already logged into ServiceNow. I want to extract some elements from the background/servicenow page source and pass it to the react app as shown below. The BOT authenticates the user by email so it would act like a SSO because he is already connected to ServiceNow with the same email id. We therefore want to simply pass that value.

[image: ServiceNow Source Page where the BOT is hosted]

```
if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        setTimeout(() => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
            payload: {
              name: 'webchat/join',

              value: {
                language: window.navigator.language,
                userid: "a.b@c.d",
                username: "a.b@c.d"
              }
            }
          });
        }, 1000);
      } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
        if (action.payload.activity.from.role === 'bot') {
          this.setState(() => ({ newMessage: true }));
        }
      }

      return next(action);
    });
```

Comment: @tdurnford Can you assist?

Comment: @StevenKanberg Is there something wrong with my code? While I ran ngrok against it redirecting the headers, it ran fine and the user was authenticated. But then it failed thereafter. I am not able to incorporate your findings onto my code. Please note that I am building this and importing it to servicenow as per [thisstep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834760/bot-framework-sample-12-implementation-on-servicenow)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are redirecting the headers using ngrok?

Comment: Okay, this one ngrok http [port] -host-header="localhost:[port]"

Comment: It's hard to know what might be wrong with your code without being able to see it. A couple questions, tho. I'm assuming you are using ngrok to test locally so as to not deploy? Have you updated the bot's messaging endpoint to use ngrok (don't forget to add "/api/messages")? Are you passing the app Id and app password? Are the auth settings configured correctly (the redirect url, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from your page to your bot by dispatching an event listener on the page and catching the event in the web chat implementation.

In this example, I am simulating a user having logged in with a button click. The button click creates the event. When the event is registered, it is picked up by web chat which then takes the values stored in `window.NOW.user` and forwards that data to the bot. To help drive the point home, I am sending a message greeting the user by name while also sending the data (name and email) behind the scenes.

Hope of help!

**app.js:** Imports the view for display.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import WebChatView from './webChatView';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/" exact component={WebChatView} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**webChatView.js:** I import the webchat component into the view and create a function that, on click (again, just to simulate someone having logged in), creates and dispatches an event.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WebChat from './webchat';

class WebChatView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.sendToBot = this.sendToBot.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <WebChat id="webchat" role="main" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="loginBtn" onClick={this.sendToBot}>Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  sendToBot = () => {
    let sendToBotEvent = new Event('sendToBot')
    window.dispatchEvent(sendToBotEvent);

    window['NOW'] = {
      'user': {
        'name': 'John Doe',
        'email': 'john.doe@somedomain.com'
      }
    }
  }
}

export default WebChatView;
```

**webchat.js:** Lastly, is web chat, itself. I create a `store` and an event listener. When the event is dispatched in the window, the message/data is also dispatched to the bot. Because I'm simulating logging in as one step, I have included a setTimeout so the `window.NOW.user` data has a chance to save. The `store` is passed to `<ReactWebChat>` which, subsequently, sends the associated data to the bot for processing.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactWebChat, { createDirectLine, createStore, } from 'botframework-webchat';

export default class WebChat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const store = window.WebChat.createStore();

    window.addEventListener('sendToBot', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: {
            name: 'Service Now user name',
            value: window.NOW.user
          }
        })
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE',
          payload: {
            text: `Hi ${window.NOW.user.name}!`
          }
        })
      }, 300)
    })
  }

  this.state = {
    store: store
  };

  componentWilUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('sendToBot', null)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.directLine ?
        <ReactWebChat
          directLine={this.state.directLine}
          store={this.state.store}
        />
        :
        <div>Connecting to bot&hellip;</div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]